# Hash function in c# not giving expected hashed password

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5, moodle

I know that this question is already asked many times but actually till now I can't find the right one for me so please help.
I want to insert new users in moodle's database by a script written in c#. What i want to do is to insert the username and a password to that user from this script. So i need to insert the hashed password. All my hashed passwords begin with "$2y$10$". In c# I tried several ways and it didn't give me the same password. For ex. I tried :

```
string cryptedPassword = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(password);
```

It gives me

> $2a&06&bQuFKC8fVPYQsGbQj3sL7uoZByn7tRc4enxBeiN2k1wu5iyubTIyi

although the expected one is

> $2y$10$SNUjOqCuwKodg0E126mHUO2NzMBnIHZl/fD/Q2wEv4hg.y5y2j4VC

.
Also the following is giving true so the crypter can hash my password in the same way as moodle script does:

```
bool matches = Crypter.CheckPassword(password, "$2y$10$SNUjOqCuwKodg0E126mHUO2NzMBnIHZl/fD/Q2wEv4hg.y5y2j4VC");
```

How can i specify the hash-algorithm = 2y = BCrypt and cost-factor = 10 = 2^10 iterations in 'Crypter.Blowfish' in a way to have the same hashed password as expected?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't specify your crypto framework, so I took a guess from Google and assume that it's CryptSharp. `BlowfishCrypter` has a function `Crypt` that accepts salt (as @rpc1 mentioned), and that salt can be generated with `GenerateSalt`, which accepts option `Rounds` for cost factor and `Variant` option of type `BlowfishCrypterVariant` — you need `Corrected` that corresponds to *$2y$*.

Comment: Maybe the question should be edited in order to specify : Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt` set  the second parameter Salt, try to set it, because when you don't set Salt parameter module used random salt for each running
try this

```
string cryptedPassword = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(password,"some_SALT");
```

Comment: when i am using 'Crypter.Blowfish.GenerateSalt(10)' it gives me the following errors: The best overloaded method match for 'CryptSharp.Crypter.GenerateSalt(CryptSharp.CrypterOptions)' has some invalid arguments and Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'CryptSharp.CrypterOptions'. Can you help me to solve this errors?

Comment: @y.h CryptSharp.CryptOptions parameter defined as `public class CrypterOptions : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<CrypterOptionKey, Object>>, IEnumerable`   <br/> You need to set IEnumerable class with, where first key is `CryptoOption', the second value <br/> is variant `BlowfishCrypterVariant` <br/> for example: <br/> `GenerateSalt(new CrypterOptions { { CrypterOption.Variant, BlowfishCrypterVariant.Unspecified} })'

Comment: useful links:
http://docs.zer7.com/cryptsharp/html/4bb2e032-860e-a970-5cc9-e228c9205201.htm

Comment: Thank you again for your help and for your quick reply:) I'm using `string cryptedpassword = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(password, new CrypterOptions(){{CrypterOption.Variant, BlowfishCrypterVariant.Corrected}, {CrypterOption.Rounds,10}});` and it's working:D

Answer (score 1):

Just to show as an answer and not as a comment (more readable):

as @y.h commented:

```
string result = Crypter.Blowfish.Crypt(cadena, 
                new CrypterOptions()
                {
                    { CrypterOption.Variant, BlowfishCrypterVariant.Corrected }, 
                    { CrypterOption.Rounds, 6 }
                });
```

This will produce something like:

$2y$06$xkdTy5YwKmMCDP6vQGC5A.YgZkKxv17xQQfMyIUNfNWazd4pqqibK

Which is a valid 2y version (plus round factor 6 )

Cheers!